# Conclude convergence in probability from uniform convergence on a set of limiting probability 1

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-process, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let

- $\kappa_d$ be a Markov kernel on $(\mathbb R^d,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$ for $d\in\mathbb N$
- $f_d:\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ be Borel measurable for $d\in\mathbb N$
- $B_d\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ for $d\in\mathbb N$ with $$\sup_{x\in B_d}\int\kappa_d(x,{\rm d}y)|f(x,y)|\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0\tag1$$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $X^{(d)}:\Omega\to\mathbb R^d$ be $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$-measurable with $$\operatorname P\left[X^{(d)}\in B_d\right]\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}1\tag2$$ for $d\in\mathbb N$
- $Y^{(d)}:\Omega\to\mathbb R^d$ be $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$-measurable with$^1$ $$Y^{(d)}_\ast\operatorname P=\left(X^{(d)}_\ast\operatorname P\right)\kappa_d\tag3$$ for $d\in\mathbb N$

> Are we able to conclude $$\left|f\left(X^{(d)},Y^{(d)}\right)\right|\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0\tag4$$ in probability (or even almost surely)?

We may note that $$\operatorname E\left[\left|f\left(X^{(d)},Y^{(d)}\right)\right|\right]=\int\operatorname P\left[X^{(d)}\in{\rm d}x\right]\int\kappa_d(x,{\rm d}y)|f(x,y)|\tag5$$ for all $d\in\mathbb N$. We may split the outer integral and clearly $$\int_{B_d}\operatorname P\left[X^{(d)}\in{\rm d}x\right]\int\kappa_d(x,{\rm d}y)|f(x,y)|\le\operatorname P\left[X^{(d)}\in B_d\right]\sup_{x\in B_d}\int\kappa_d(x,{\rm d}y)|f(x,y)|\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0\tag6.$$ So, a possible way would to show $$\int_{\mathbb R^d\setminus B_d}\operatorname P\left[X^{(d)}\in{\rm d}x\right]\int\kappa_d(x,{\rm d}y)|f(x,y)|\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0\tag7.$$ If the inner integral wouldn't depend on $d$, [this would be a simple application of the dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2211461/47771). However, since it depends on $d$, this might be problematic.

---

$^1$ $\left(X^{(d)}_\ast\operatorname P\right)\kappa_d$ denotes the [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Composition_of_kernels) of the distribution $X^{(d)}_\ast\operatorname P$ of $X^{(d)}$ under $\operatorname P$ and $\kappa_d$.