# Convergence in probability implies convergence in $L_{2}$ (Wrong Proof?)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have $X_{n} \overset{p}{\to} X$
Then,
$$
\int_{\Omega} \vert X_{n}-X\vert^{2} = \int_{\Omega} \vert X_{n}-X\vert^{2} \mathbb{1}_{\vert X_{n}-X\vert > \epsilon} + \int_{\Omega} \vert X_{n}-X\vert^{2} \mathbb{1}_{\vert X_{n}-X\vert \leq \epsilon}
\\
< \int_{\Omega} \vert X_{n}-X\vert^{2} \mathbb{1}_{\vert X_{n}-X\vert > \epsilon}+\epsilon^{2}\int_{\Omega}  \mathbb{1}_{\vert X_{n}-X\vert \leq \epsilon}
\\
< \int_{\Omega} \vert X_{n}-X\vert^{2} \mathbb{1}_{\vert X_{n}-X\vert > \epsilon} + \epsilon^{2}
$$

Does it not then follow that since $\lim_{n} P(\vert X_{n}-X\vert > \epsilon)=0$ that the first integral of the last line converges to 0 in the limit? [Since the limit of sets is of probability 0, it follows that the limit of integral is 0 as well?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211461/limit-of-lebesgue-integral-on-a-sequence-of-set-whose-measure-tends-to-zero)

Comment: You did not even mention the assumption that $X_n$ have finite second moment. $\int X1_{A_n} \to 0$ if $P(A_n) \to 0$ and $X$ is integeable. You cannot replace $X$ by a squence  of r.v.'s. with finite second moment. $X$ has to be independent of $n$.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now. So if X was independent of n as in say [here where X was bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741523/show-that-convergence-in-probabiltiy-plus-domination-implies-l-p-convergence) then it would work. Though could you please explain the relevance of $X_{n}$ having finite second moments? Are you saying that you can bound the $|X_{n} - X|^{2}$ given finite second moments of $X_{n}$?

Comment: $X_{n} \overset{p}{\to} X$ does not imply that $E|X_n-X|^{2}\to 0$ because we may have $E|X_n-X|^{2}=\infty$ for every $n$. Some thing more than just convergence in probabiltiy is needed to say that $E|X_n-X|^{2}\to 0$.